# WMI Printer properties zero or null

Tags: c#, wmi

I'm playing around with WMI to see what information I get from a Printer in comparison to SNMP OID requests and Win32-Api functions.

Now if I take my Printers via `Select * From Win32_Printer` a few properties are always null or 0 (zero) e.g `AveragePagesPerMinute`, which are not with SNMP or the Win32 functions to get the devicecapabilities.

Am I doing something wrong or do I have to use another WMI class to retrieve these information? Is it even possible to get correct printer devicecaps via WMI?